# Pass list of one of two structures to the function

Tags: list, go, struct, union

New in Go, couldn't find any intuitive way of doing that.

I have such piece of code

```
tx = getTx()
for _, record := range tx.a {
    // do a lot with record.Important
}
for _, record := range tx.b {
    // do a lot with record.Important
}
for _, record := range tx.c {
    // do a lot with record.Important
}
```

And the following structs:

```
type Record1 struct {
    // fields of Record1
    Important string
}
type Record2 struct {
    // fields of Record1
    Important string
}
type TX struct {
    a []Record1
    b []Record1
    c []Record2
}
```

Now the logical is to extract every **for** logic into the function:

```
func helper(records) { // Here is the problem
   // do a lot with record.Important
}
```

Problem:

**records** is a `[]Record1` or `[]Record2` type. But it looks like Union types doesn't exists in Golang. So I thought I could pass `[]string` into the **helper**, but cannot even find an elegant way to get something equivalent to `map(lambda r: r.Important, tx.a)`. There is no high order **map** function, no list comprehesion. I am not convinced to use raw **for** loop to solve that.

Comment: Use an interface or generics or reflection. The name of the language is "Go".

Comment: You should read about interfaces and composition.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to do the loop across multiple types is to use interfaces together with generics. Have each `Record` type implement a getter method for the important field. Then declare an interface that includes that getter method in its method set. Then you can make your `helper` generic by declaring the interface as its type parameter.

```golang
func (r Record1) GetImportant() string { return r.Important }
func (r Record2) GetImportant() string { return r.Important }

type ImportantGetter interface {
     GetImporant() string
}

func helper[T ImportantGetter](s []T) {
    for _, v := range s {
        _ = v.GetImportant()
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be `return r.Important`?

Comment: Yes sir, very much so! Fixed. @kosciej16

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, it seems like you want to extract all the values in column X from a set of records and then pass those values in as a slice to some function - I'm basing my assumption on your wish that go had something like `map()`.

If what you're after is type-agnosticism, you could certainly use an interface approach like that suggested by [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva), but you aren't going to get out of using a `for` loop - iteration over list types is core to idiomatic go.  If you need a mapping function, you're going to have to write one that performs the mapping you want.

I'd note that you do not need generics to do what [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva) suggests, you can just use an interface without muddying the waters with generics [go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/t9Qsv4cpVPk):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Record1 struct {
    Important string
}

type Record2 struct {
    Important string
}

func (r Record1) GetImportant() string { return r.Important }
func (r Record2) GetImportant() string { return r.Important }

type ImportantGetter interface {
    GetImportant() string
}

func helper(s []ImportantGetter) {
    for _, v := range s {
        fmt.Println(v.GetImportant())
    }
}

func main() {
    records := []ImportantGetter{Record1{Important: "foo"}, Record2{Important: "bar"}}

    helper(records)
}
```

Another approach to the type-agnosticism, and one that's a bit more (IMHO) idiomatic for "I expect all of these types to have a common property," is to use `struct` embedding and type assertions to build your own `Map()` function up [go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ct4m9Ph4IxY):

```
type CommonFields struct {
    Important string
}

type Record1 struct {
    CommonFields
    FieldSpecificToRecord1 string
}

type Record2 struct {
    CommonFields
    FieldSpecificToRecord2 int
}

func main() {
    r1 := Record1{
        CommonFields{Important: "I'm r1!"},
        "foo",
    }

    r2 := Record2{
        CommonFields{Important: "I'm r2!"},
        5,
    }

    records := []interface{}{r1, r2, "this is not a valid record type"}

    fmt.Println(Map(records))

}

func Map(source []interface{}) []string {
    destination := make([]string, len(source))
    for i, sourceRecord := range source {
        if rr, ok := sourceRecord.(Record1); ok {
            destination[i] = rr.Important
        } else if rr, ok := sourceRecord.(Record2); ok {
            destination[i] = rr.Important
        } else {
            destination[i] = "undefined"
        }
    }
    return destination
}
```

You'd likely want to make your implementation of `Map()` accept an argument specifying the field to extract to conform to what you have in other languages, or possibly even just pass in a helper function which does most of the type-specific value extraction.